# create a 2D array from a 1D array and a Boolean array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I'm trying to create a 2d array from these array

```
A=[5, 7, 1, -3, 0, 2, 2, 7, 10, 11, -1, 8, 5, 18, 9]

B=[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True]
```

I hope to get a matrix like this

```
C= [[1, -3, 0],
    [2, 7],
    [8],
    [18,9]]
```

that is, every time that change the array B from False to True, create a new row with consecutive True values.

please someone can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular integer NumPy arrays cannot have a jagged shape, e.g. for a 2d array, each row must have the same numbers of columns. But you can create a list of arrays via [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
lst_of_array = np.split(A, np.where(np.diff(B) == 1)[0]+1)[{0:1,1:0}[B[0]]::2]

# [array([ 1, -3,  0]),
#  array([2, 7]),
#  array([8]),
#  array([18,  9])]
```

Or for a list of lists:

```
from operator import methodcaller

lst_of_lst = list(map(methodcaller('tolist'), lst_of_array))

# [[1, -3, 0],
#  [2, 7],
#  [8],
#  [18, 9]]
```

Comment: Using `[1::2]` will only be correct if the first element of the B array is `False`. If the first element is `True`, it should be `[0::2]`

Comment: Easiest way to sneak this in might be `np.split(A, np.where(np.diff(B) == 1)[0]+1)[(0 if B[0] else 1)::2]`. At this point, it's starting to lose readability though

Comment: @user8408080, Yup, just happened to update with a dictionary solution.. since the theme is functional.

Comment: You could actually also go with `not B[0]`, which is even a bit shorter, but I guess this is just a matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using a generator. No real reason to use a generator rather than a function actually, just what I first jumped to.

```
def splitter(A, B):
    sublist = []
    for item, check in zip(A, B):
        if not check:
            if sublist:
                yield sublist 
                sublist = []
        else:
            sublist.append(item)
    if sublist:
        yield sublist

A = [5, 7, 1, -3, 0, 2, 2, 7, 10, 11, -1, 8, 5, 18, 9]
B = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True]

list(splitter(A, B))
```

Output:

```
[[1, -3, 0], [2, 7], [8], [18, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm loops through `A`, accumulates consecutive `true` `A` values into `D`, until a `false` `A` value has been encountered, and only adds `D` to `C` if it has accumulated any `true` values in it. Finally, on the last loop through it appends `D` to `C` , again, if `D` has any values.

```
C = []
D = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if B[i]:
        D.append(A[i])
    elif len(D):
        C.append(D)
        D = []
    if i == len(A)-1 and len(D):
        C.append(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, ifilter, izip
from operator import itemgetter

get_0 = itemgetter(0)

A=[5, 7, 1, -3, 0, 2, 2, 7, 10, 11, -1, 8, 5, 18, 9]
B=[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True]

list((list((vv for _, vv in v))
    for _, v in
       ifilter(get_0, groupby(izip(B,A), get_0))))
```

Result:

```
[[1, -3, 0], [2, 7], [8], [18, 9]]
```